# SQL Views Taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have an SQL querry that creates a comparison table based on taxonomy and am wondering if it is possible to recreate using Views??

If a node has a taxonomy it selects the node tile and 'Y' else 'N'
A sample of the SQL code is:

```
enter code here

select a.title AS SOFTWARE,
COALESCE((select 'Y'
from taxonomy_index b, taxonomy_term_data c
where c.tid = b.tid
and c.vid = 3
and b.tid = 17
and a.nid = b.nid), 'N') AS 'Results Recorded',
COALESCE((select 'Y'
from taxonomy_index b, taxonomy_term_data c
where c.tid = b.tid
and c.vid = 3
and b.tid = 13
and a.nid = b.nid), 'N') AS 'Free Trial'
from node a
where a.type = 'Software'
```

Many Thanks
Julie

Answer (score 0):

Building this query in Views impossible, but you can use PHP code (for example, [views_php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php), [views_customfield](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield), [viewsphpfilter](http://drupal.org/project/viewsphpfilter)) or just templating fields in Views for making dynamic calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have installed views_php but I am not sure how I use it to get the desired results. My SQL is poor and my PHP is worse. Could you point me to an example of how I would use views_php to implement the above query.

Comment: I am repeat, doing your sql is impossible. You should just query your nodes with taxonomy, then write code in PHP for calculation Y and N...